# NuGet package is not completely installed

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget, devops, nlog

I am creating a NuGet package via Azure DevOps. The NuGet package contains an Example.exe file and an Example.exe.nlog file. So far all is well. WWhen I install the NuGet into my project in Visual Studio, only the Example.exe is added. The Example.exe.nlog is missing.
It is not clear to me why this is not also added to the project.

As a test I have added an Example.dll as well. But this is added to the project. Why not the .exe.nlog?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Is the .nlog file included in the Nuget package? How have you added it? It's impossible for us to tell what is going wrong with no code. Do you have a nuspec file?

Comment: The exe.nlog file has been added to the .nuspec with <file src>. When I download the NuGet package manually then the exe.nlog is present. Also in Visual Studio in the package folder, where all NuGet packages are, the exe.nlog is included. But in the bin folder the exe.nlog is missing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. I have to add "content\Folder\Folder" in the nuspec target Tag

Comment: Now I have another problem. I have a solution in Visual Studio with several projects. The Nuget package is referenced in project 1, but a file needs to be placed in project 2. How do I specify the target path?

Thank you.